# what is the syntax for a __stdcall name decoration?

Tags: c, calling-convention, name-decoration

I have a program that calls a set of function as follows:

```
int _stdcall VB_Create(char*);
int _stdcall VB_Open(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);
...
...
```

If there is a mismatch in the name decoration, the linker shows an error like this:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall VB_Create(char *)" (?VB_Create@@YGHPAD@Z) .....
```

My understanding is that `_stdcall` syntax is an `'_' + 'name of the function' + '@' + 'number of arguments * 4'`.

So, why the linker is asking for `?VB_Create@@YGHPAD@Z` name decoration? what standard is this?

Comment: It varies from one compiler to the next. What compiler are you using? And that name isn't a calling convention standard, it's basic C++ name mangling, which is how the compiler translates your C++ method names to C function names (at the assembly level there's no such thing as a method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Visual C++ name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling) (I don't know that there is an official page on MSDN to describe the encoding; I could not find one).

C++ functions need more than just their name encoded into the symbol that ends up in the binary:  those symbols need to be unique, but C++ function names need not be unique.  Among other reasons, C++ functions can be overloaded, you can have functions with the same name in different namespaces, and you have to be able to handle member functions.

A compiler uses a compact encoding scheme, like this one, so that functions can be uniquely identiifed.

Comment: It is reverse engineered: See http://mearie.org/documents/mscmangle/, which Wikipedia cites as its source.

Answer (score 2):

James already said it: it is a name mangling issue. Put a

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

before and a

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

after the function declarations. That will turn off C++ name mangling. FWIW, `__stdcall` has nothing to do with this, although it is required for VB, IIRC.

Comment: IIRC = If I Remember Correctly.

Comment: For some reason I thought it was a protocol or something like that. ;-). Thanks.

Comment: @Peretz: LOL! It is common Usenet slang, just like LOL, IMO (originally IMHO), AFAIK, AFAICT, IME, YMMV, etc.

Comment: Haha, it seems that my usenet slang is quite poor. ;-)